# Yoneda as a dinatural transformation 'up to iso'

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, yoneda-lemma

$\newcommand{\op}{\mathrm{op}}$For a locally small category $\mathcal{C}$, let $y_\mathcal{C}:\mathcal{C}\to{\bf Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\op}}$ denote the Yoneda embedding at $\mathcal{C}$. Letting ${\bf Cat}$ denote the $1$-category of locally small categories, we have a functor $${\bf Set}^{-^{\op}}:{\bf Cat}\to{\bf Cat}^{\op}$$ $$\mathcal{C}\mapsto{\bf Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\op}}$$
$$F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}'\longmapsto\circ F^{\op}:{\bf Set}^{\mathcal{C}'^{\op}}\to{\bf Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{\op}}$$
where $\circ F^{\op}$ is precomposition with the opposite functor of $F$, and the Yoneda embeddings together almost yield a [dinatural transformation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dinatural+transformation) $$y:1_{\bf Cat}\Rightarrow{\bf Set}^{-^{\op}}$$ whose components at each category are given by the various Yoneda embeddings, except that the appropriate dinaturality diagram

[image]

for a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ doesn't commute on the nose, it only commutes up to $$F_{-,-}:{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,-)\Rightarrow{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F(-),F(-))$$ where ${\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}(-,-),{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{D}(F(-),F(-)):\mathcal{C}^{\op}\times\mathcal{C}\to{\bf Set}$ are the hom-functor at $\mathcal{C}$ and the hom-functor induced by $F$, respectively. We further have that $F$ is fully faithful iff $F_{-,-}$ is a natural isomorphism, so the dinaturality diagram above commutes 'up to canonical iso' if we restrict our attention to the wide subcategory of ${\bf Cat}$ consisting of fully faithful functors.

This is certainly common knowledge, so

> what are some references leveraging this view on Yoneda, or some interesting consequences of it?

Commuting 'up to a $2$-cell in $\mathfrak{Cat}$' makes me think this is probably clearest from a $2$-categorical perspective; we can extend the above discussion to be about ${\bf Set}^{-^{\op}}:\mathfrak{Cat}\to\mathfrak{Cat}^{(1,2)-\op}$, which is what a written-up reference probably does. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I don’t know a reference leveraging this particularly.  One way to see it is as arising from the simpler (pseudo-)naturality of $y$ with respect to the *covariant* (2-)functoriality of presheaves: $F : C \to D$ goes to $F_! : \hat{C} \to \hat{D}$ (where $F_!$ is $\mathrm{Lan}_{y_C} F$, the left adjoint to $F^*$).  Then the adjunction $F_! \dashv F^*$ transforms the canonical iso $F_! y_C \cong y_D F$ into your map $y_C \to F^* y_D F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, in fact, a rather big picture studying this kind of phenomena "in general", i.e. not only for the Yoneda embedding into presheaves of sets:

R. Street, "Conspectus of variable categories" https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(81)90021-9

See in particular §6 and what precedes.

Comment: Street pretty unfailingly explores the 'most general' version of categorical phenomenon, and I love him for it; thank you fosco.